# How to find the variance of $C\hat\beta$?

Tags: normal-distribution, proof

Assuming a Gauss-Markov model such that $H_o$: $C\beta$ = $d$,

how do I prove that the variance of $C\hat\beta$~ $N(C\beta, \sigma^2C(x'X)^-C')$   ?

My Work...Which I Know is Not Correct, when assuming it is testable:

Prove $Var(C\hat{\beta}$) = $\sigma^2C(X'X)^-C'$

Let $\hat{\beta}$ = $(X'X)^-X'y$   By definition.

$C = AX$   Given $C\beta$ is estimable, for some matrix A.

=$\sigma^2AX(X'X)^-AX'y$   Substitution.

=$\sigma^2AX(X'X)^-X'AA'$   Var(y) in linear transformation = AVar(y)A'.

$Px=X(X'X)^-X'$   Def. of projection operator.

=$\sigma^2APxAA'$    Substitution.

....don't know how to finish.

Comment: See edit to title for how to put a hat on $\beta$. What should C9 be? This needs some clean-up to be clearer.

Comment: @NickCox I fixed this, do you know how to correctly finish?

Comment: See here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyBtfhQsf44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jennifer, here is how I would approach this.  There were a few problems with your attempt above and your final answer was incorrect.

Assuming you do not need to show that $\hat\beta=(X'X)^-X'y$, but that it is given, and assuming $y\sim N(XB, \sigma^2I)$ then:

$Var(C\hat\beta)=Var[C(X'X)^-X'y]$ (by definition)

Let $A=C(X'X)^-X'$.  Then,

$Var[C(X'X)^-X'y]=Var(Ay)$

$=AVar(y)A'$ (by definition of quadratic form)

$=[C(X'X)^-X']Var(y)[C(X'X)^-X']'$ (by definition of A)

$=[C(X'X)^-X']\sigma^2I[C(X'X)^-X']'$ (by Gauss-Markov Assumption)

$=\sigma^2[C(X'X)^-X'][C(X'X)^-X']'$ (since $\sigma^2$ is a scalar and $I$ is the identity matrix)

$=\sigma^2[C(X'X)^-X'][(X(X'X)^-C']$ (by distributing the transpose on the right bracketed term)

$=\sigma^2C\left\{[(X'X)^-(X'X)](X'X)^-C'\right\}$ (by the associative property of matrices)

$=\sigma^2C[I(X'X)^-C']$ (by definition of the the inverse)

$=\sigma^2C(X'X)^-C'$ (by definition of the identity matrix, $I$)   $\blacksquare$

Hopefully this helps clear up the problems you were facing.  One last thing, note that $X'X$ does not have to be strictly invertible but the $generalized$ inverse must exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe is the correct answer after studying this weekend. Please review this answer.

Prove $Var(C\hat\beta) = \sigma^2C(X'X)^-C'$, assuming Gauss-Markov model with normal errors.

$\hat\beta=C(X'X)-X'$ - a linear transformation, given columns of $X$ are linearly independent and $X'X$ is invertible.

$C\hat\beta$ is OLSE of $C\beta$ - BY GMMNE

$\hat\beta y=C(X'X)^-X'y$ - A transformation of y vector.

$Var(\hat\beta y) = \hat\beta Var(y)\hat\beta'$ - General form of variance linear transformation.

$ = [C(X'X^-X'y]Var(y)[C(X'X^-X'y]'$ - Expanded form, substitute.

$= [C(X'X^-X'y]\sigma^2 I [C(X'X^-X'y]'$ - By GMMNE, $Var(y) = \sigma^2 I$.

$= [C(X'X^-X'y]\sigma^2 I (C'(X'X^-X'y)'$ - Distribute prime.

$=\sigma^2C(X'X)^-X'y$ - Simplified. I is idempotent.

Therefore, $C\hat\beta$ has distribution with variance = $\sigma^2C(X'X)^-X'y$

Comment: I don't know how you arrived at $\hat\beta y=C(X'X)^-X'y$.  Was the $C$ a typo?  You will also need to maintain the parantheses around the $X'X$.  Did you watch the video I referred to under your original post?

Comment: @StatsStudent I looked over your answer, which now makes sense. I didn't recognize a lot of the matrix-related properties that I could put to use. I need to get these down pat! How might I do that? Thanks, and I'd like to take this to chat.